# Where to put a command to run once when computer starts - using zsh

Tags: zsh

I can't find it easily in Google.

I tried `~/.profile` but it seems to be running for each tab.

Where can I find a mapping: `file` ---> `when runs`?

## Update

I am in Ubuntu, I put it in `/etc/rc.local` but command is not being executed:

```
my_command
exit 0
```

Comment: each tab is a different shell session. If you don't want this command to run before each shell session when do you want it to run? When the computer boots up? The way you do that will likely depend on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping of when each file runs is described in `man zshall`, search for `STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES`.

[...]

As others pointed out, you need to make clearer what you mean by *run once*. Once per boot? Once per desktop login?

Once per *login shell* is `~/.profile` but you can always start more login shells.

If you have a block of shell code that you really want to execute only once, you should perform sensible checks to see if you ran it already, like:

- use a common lock to avoid races, then create a file on `/tmp`, say `/ran/withsuccess` and then `chmod -w`. It will get deleted on reboot (assuming your OS does that...)
- (if acceptable) you can also change the code that starts your desktop session, but that would get run twice if you did 2 graphical logins
- code below for `gpg-agent`

To avoid starting `gpg-agent` twice, I check env variables and later see if I can connect:

```
# Effectively checks if GPG_ENV is set and if it is set to an existing file 
if [ -f "${GPG_ENV}" ]; then
   # assumes gpg-agent is set... try to connect
   gpg-connect-agent 'getinfo socket_name' /bye &> /dev/null
   if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]; then
    start_agent
   fi
else
   # runs the gpg-agent start-up which I do not want to run twice
   start_agent
 fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a Mac?  Use [`launchd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd)..

Create a `plist` akin to...

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mycompany.startupscript</string>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/startupscript</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>`

Plop it in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, with proper `-rw-r--r--   root  wheel` permissions'... and you too, can achieve *startup script nirvana*.